# Matching data frame rows based on opposite values of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform a calculation on this table of movements between location codes, snippet below:

```
origin     destination age sex  moves
E06000019   E06000019   98  m   0
E06000019   E06000019   99  f   0
E06000019   E06000019   99  m   0
E06000019   E06000019   100 f   0
E06000019   E06000019   100 m   0
E06000019   E06000020   0   f   0.3632
E06000019   E06000020   0   m   0.8249
E06000019   E06000020   1   f   1.1931
E06000019   E06000020   1   m   1.192
```

The aim is to find the net flow between any two locations, e.g:
(1) match each row to another row, in which the age and sex are the same but the origin/destination are the opposite way around. Then (2) subtract the number of moves in the second row from the number of moves in the first row.

I have tried creating nested loops or defining a function before using apply:

```
df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.col_1, x.col_2), axis=1)
```

But in both cases I have had difficulty understanding how to create a match for every row.

Anyone have any ideas on how I might approach this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you change an example so that there are some rows that respect the condition? I can't see any pair of rows that have the same age and sex

Comment: your data doesn't follow your logic - can you add in your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You gave a bad example: the first 4 rows have the same `origin` and `destination` so they will inevitably match themselves.

Having said that, your problem can be solved with a self-join:

```
df.merge(df, how='left', suffixes=('', '_'),
         left_on=['origin', 'destination', 'age', 'sex'], 
         right_on=['destination', 'origin', 'age', 'sex']) \
    .assign(delta=lambda x: x['moves_'] - x['moves'])
```